# How to remove a concrete-filled, steel bollard

Tags: steel, demolition

I have a set of permanent, steel bollards set into a small concrete slab that I need to remove, in order make room to build a small structure.  The steel is 1/4" thick, and the bollards themselves are open on top and filled to the rim with concrete.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way (cheapest + quickest) to accomplish this.  At the moment, the best idea I have come up with is using a blowtorch and sledgehammer.

For those of you who need a picture, this attached picture is about as close to what I'm dealing with as I can find.

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Is it okay to destroy the concrete platform?

Comment: Perhaps partially, but my intention is to use the existing slab as a foundation for the new structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use (if you can fit it on) or replicate the function of a "lally column cutter" - I suspect replicate the function will be the better bet - use a cutoff disk in an angle grinder to score a line around the base of the steel (not a piddly little score, ideally - deepish, but it need not hit concrete) and then smack the top of the column. Enjoy the power of "stress concentration" as the steel snaps at the score-line, and the concrete will go with it.

Be sure that your new structure provides adequate protection to whatever you are building a structure over (I'm gathering the hydrant is an example, not the actual thing) if being plowed into by a vehicle remains an issue; which presumably is why there are bollards there in the first place.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I will try this.